# how to use geocode()

Tags: google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reverse Geocode On Google Maps api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883440/reverse-geocode-on-google-maps-api-v3)

I want to find the address by using lat-lang value for that I'm using new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode()
following is the implementation of the method

```
function checkAddress(){
  var address="";
  var amstr = new google.maps.LatLng(37.556179,-122.288219);
  address = getAddress(amstr);
  alert(address);

}

function getAddress(latLng) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( {'latLng': latLng},
        function(results, status) {
         if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if(results[0]) {            
        return results[0].formatted_address;
          }
          else {
            return "No results";
          }
        }
        else {
          return "not working";
        }
      });
    }
```

but after running above code I'm getting 'undefined' as result.
Please tell me where I'm doing it wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: then what should be done to get address from lat-lng

Comment: can you give me an example because i don't know how to do that

Comment: @SLaks, he *is* using a callback, (anonymous function inline), but it is not returning to where he expects it. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`geocoder.geocode()` is asynchronous.  It only calls your callback some time after the rest of your code finishes.

You need to return the value in a callback:

```
function getAddress(latLng, callback) {
    ...
    geocoder.geocode(..., function(...) {
        ...
        callback(someValue);
    });
}
```

Comment: now i got it !!! Thanks SLaks & Marcelo !!!!